# working with the selected DataGridView row in C#

Tags: c#, object, datagridview

is there a way to cast/convert the currently selected Row in a datagridview to a custom Object?

For example, I'm trying to cast the selected row to an object of type Client, however, I am unable to do so using this method.

```
DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection rows = dgvClient.SelectedRows;
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in rows)
{
    DataRow myRow = (r.DataBoundItem as DataRowView).Row;
    Client current = (Client)myRow;
}
```

Comment: A DataGridViewRow does not inherit from Client, so why would you be able to cast to it?

Comment: You can't cast something from what it is to something it isn't.

Comment: You should post which DataGrid you're using (Toolkit or .NET 4.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use implicit and explicit operator
for eg

```
class Client
{
   public static explicit operator Client(DataRow dr)
   {
      // code to convert from dr to Client
   }
}

Client current = (Client)myRow;
```

similarly you could overload implicit. With implicit operator you the conversion would take automatically with out casts

Comment: Essentially this is doing what I recommend in having a constructor in the class that takes the DataRow as a parameter. +1 for the explicit operator, though ...  ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, because `DataRow` has no relation to `Client` - i.e., Client is not derived from DataRow.
**Edit**: I stand corrected, you can provide an explicit method of casting as @Anand explains. I would recommend this if the `Client` source is inaccessible. Otherwise ...

I had a project in VB.Net that used a List as the data source for a DataGridView. What was interesting is that I was able to cast the selected row to `SomeEntity`.

What I recommend is provide a constructor, in this case for `Client`, that accepts a DataRow as a parameter. Assign values from the row and be done with it:

```
Client current = new Client(myRow);
```